# WPF Grid Panel.ZIndex set to 1 is not working in case of another window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, xaml

I am building an app in WPF and I want to show a navigation stack panel to appear always on top of every other child window, just like how a menu bar functions.

My MainWindow.xaml has this code in a grid.

```
<!--// Navigation Panel //-->

<Grid
    x:Name="nav_pnl"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    Width="65"
    Background="#2E333A"
    Panel.ZIndex="1"
    >

    <StackPanel
        x:Name="st_pnl"
        >

        <Grid
            Background="#FF225277"
            Height="100"
            >

            <TextBlock
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Margin="73,-20,0,0"
                Text="COMPANY"
                Foreground="White"
                FontSize="22"
                Background="Transparent"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Style="{StaticResource styl_tb_font1}"
                >

            </TextBlock>

            <ToggleButton 
                x:Name="Tg_Btn"
                Grid.Column="0"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Margin="18,-20,0,0"
                Height="30"
                Width="30"
                >

                <ToggleButton.Background>

                    <ImageBrush
                        ImageSource="Assets/tgBtn_default.png"
                        Stretch="None"
                    />

                </ToggleButton.Background>


            </ToggleButton>

        </Grid>

        <!--// ListView with menu list items //-->

        <ListView
            x:Name="LV"
            Background="Transparent"
            BorderBrush="Transparent"
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
            >

            <ListViewItem
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Margin="0,0,0,15"
                PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="Dashboard__Click"
                IsSelected="True"
                >

                <StackPanel
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    Width="230"
                    >

                    <Image
                        Source="Assets/ico_dashbrd.ico"
                        Stretch="Fill"
                        Width="30"
                        Height="30"
                        Margin="12,0,0,0"
                    />

                    <TextBlock
                        Text="Dashboard"
                        Margin="25,0,0,0"
                        Style="{StaticResource styl_tb_font1}"
                    />

                </StackPanel>

            </ListViewItem>

            <ListViewItem
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Margin="0,0,0,15"
                >

                <StackPanel
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    Width="230"
                    >

                    <Image
                        Source="Assets/icon2.ico"
                        Stretch="Fill"
                        Width="30"
                        Height="30"
                        Margin="12,0,0,0"
                    />

                    <TextBlock
                        Text="Preference"
                        Margin="25,0,0,0"
                        Style="{StaticResource styl_tb_font1}"
                    />

                </StackPanel>

            </ListViewItem>

            <ListViewItem
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Margin="0,0,0,15"
                >

                <StackPanel
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    Width="230"
                    >

                    <Image
                        Source="Assets/icon3.ico"
                        Stretch="Fill"
                        Width="30"
                        Height="30"
                        Margin="12,0,0,0"
                    />

                    <TextBlock
                        Text="Sign Out"
                        Margin="25,0,0,0"
                        Style="{StaticResource styl_tb_font1}"
                    />

                </StackPanel>

            </ListViewItem>

    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

A separate window opens on click of the Dashboard.
Here is the cs code :

```
private void Dashboard__Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Window1 wndw1 = new Window1();
    wndw1.Owner = this;
    wndw1.Show();
}
```

The problem here is shown in the screenshot. [image: wpf navigation panel]

While navigating on the panel, it must appear on the topmost of all the child windows so as to easily switch to another window (just like a menu bar). How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you talking about a menu bar across the top row of the window?  Because when you say "on top of every other window" it sorta makes it sound as if you're talking about Z-order.  (i. e. completely covering everything.)

Comment: You need to use ControlTemplate to assign it to every window. Also look into MvvM all those names just scream memory leak.

Comment: @Joe Yes I am talking about the behavior similar to a menu bar. And as you mentioned about the Z-order, as far as my knowledge is concerned, it works only in the scope of a window (and not for other windows).

Comment: @XAMlMAX Didn't get. Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have found the solution to this.

I just added a parent as `<Popup>` to the code above and it is working as expected. Now it also works when the child window has a property `Topmost=true`.

The code now looks like :

```
<Popup
  IsOpen="True"
  StaysOpen="True"
  Placement="Relative"
  Grid.Row="1"
  >

  <!-- // Grid named st_pnl -->

</Popup>
```